# Using Graph API to create a notebook in a SharePoint site, can I specify the document library?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote

Following the Graph API documentation for creating a OneNote notebook [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/onenote-post-notebooks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I can readily create a new notebook in a SharePoint site. But I have no control of where in that site the notebook is created. By default it's creating the new notebook in a "Notebooks" folder in the "Documents" document library on the site. But I want to put it in a different folder, how can I do that? If I need to create it in the default location, and then use another API call to move it, that's fine.